# SSH to ubuntu server doesn't give me a login shell

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

After manually build bash 5.3, and set environment variable PATH to /tools/bash,
when I ssh to server, it uses my build bash and gives me a non-login shell.
I'm confused what was happen in this process, since I only change the PATH, this is still a ssh shell but why it is non-login?

Comment: What does your /etc/passwd entry have as the shell for the user that you are connecting to using ssh?

Comment: As in the previous comment, what shell does this account have in /etc/passwd? How did you set PATH to /tools/bash? Please [edit] your question to include any relevant parts of your .bashrc, .profile, etc.

Comment: IIRC your "new" bash will also need to be added to `/etc/shells` in order to be a valid login shell - if you use `chsh` to change your user's login shell, it will likely warn you if that's not been done - but if you manually edit `/etc/passwd` you risk locking yourself out

Comment: yep, my /etc/passwd set /bin/bash to this user's default shell, and the .bashrc set /tools/bash:/bin/bash, so i think the process it my ssh login to /bin/bash and then switch to /tools/bash? How could this change can be done?

Comment: Well after change my /etc/passwd/ to /tools/bin/bash, it still a non-login shell @_@

Answer (score 1):

OK, i think i finally find the problem is in my bash_profile, i put a 'evn' command which execute in /bin/bash, and then my login shell go through another shell which is a non-login but interactive shell.

Now i put all my setting to bash_profile and everything works fine.

Anyway, thanks for you guys explain about how passwd work with chsh, it not quite solving my problem but make this whole thing more clear:-)